# Windows hangs when multi-monitor setup is rearranged

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dwm

I currently have 3 monitors, usually I also have 1 TV on the setup. When the TV is present, it's connected to a Yamaha A2050, which is connected to PC by HDMI. ATM Yamaha is connected to one of my monitors.

Sometimes, when I change Yamaha's input or turn off TV, or now when I change monitor input from PC (DVI-D) to Yamaha (HDMI), Windows understands that the display was disconected. Windows tries to rearrange monitors layout, that leads to a long time DWM hang and moves windows to different positions.

I believe the situation gets worsse because Yamaha display is set as main display.

I'd like Windows/DWM to stop freaking out and hanging. Whatever is making displays seem disconnected will bring them back soon enough.

Is there a way to disable this "feature"?

Comment: Have you updated your video drivers to the latest?

Comment: Yes it's updated. That answer is interesting, I'm gona read it in detail, but I can't find where to set monitor as non-PnP.